# Kafka Connect issue when reading from a RabbitMQ queue

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm trying to read data into my topic from a RabbitMQ queue using the Kafka connector with the configuration below:

```
{
  "name" : "RabbitMQSourceConnector1",
  "config" : {
   "connector.class" : "io.confluent.connect.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSourceConnector",
   "tasks.max" : "1",
   "kafka.topic" : "rabbitmqtest3",
   "rabbitmq.queue" : "taskqueue",
    "rabbitmq.host" : "localhost",
    "rabbitmq.username" : "guest",
    "rabbitmq.password" : "guest",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true"

  }
}
```

But I´m having troubles when converting the source stream to JSON format  as I´m losing the original message

Original:

```
{'id': 0, 'body': '010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010'}
```

Received:

```
{"schema":{"type":"bytes","optional":false},"payload":"eyJpZCI6IDEsICJib2R5IjogIjAxMDEwMTAxMDEwMTAxMDEwMTAxMDEwMTAxMDEwMTAxMDEwMTAxMDEwMTAxMDEwMTAxMDEwMTAxMDEwMTAxMDEwMTAxMCJ9"}
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

EDIT: I tried to convert the message to String using the     "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter", but the result is the same:

```
11/27/19 4:07:37 PM CET , 0 , [B@1583a488
```

EDIT2:

I´m now receiving the JSON file but the content is still encoded in BASE64

Any idea on how to convert it back to UTF8 directly?

```
{
 "name": "adls-gen2-sink",
 "config": {
   "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.azure.datalake.gen2.AzureDataLakeGen2SinkConnector",
   "tasks.max":"1",
   "topics":"rabbitmqtest3",
   "flush.size":"3",
   "format.class":"io.confluent.connect.azure.storage.format.json.JsonFormat",
   "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
   "internal.value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
   "topics.dir":"sw66jsoningest",
   "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers":"localhost:9092",
   "confluent.topic.replication.factor":"1",
   "partitioner.class" : "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner"

          }
}
```

UPDATE:

I got the solution, considering this flow:

Message (JSON) --> RabbitMq (ByteArray) --> Kafka (ByteArray) -->ADLS (JSON)

I used this converter on the RabbitMQ to Kafka connector to decode the message from Base64 to UTF8.

```
"value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter"
```

Afterwards I treated the message as a String and saved it as a JSON.

```
"value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
"format.class":"io.confluent.connect.azure.storage.format.json.JsonFormat",
```

Comment: Actually the rabbitmq message is all binary so most likely what you are getting is the base64 encoded value against the payload attribute , you should try out reading the data with the avro consumer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `schemas.enable": "false"`, you shouldn't be getting the schema and payload fields

If you want no translation to happen at all, use ByteArrayConverter

If your data is just a plain string (which includes JSON), use StringConverter

It's not clear how you're printing the resulting message, but looks like you're printing the byte array and not decoding it to a String

Comment: You're right ,  schemas.enable": "true " was true, sorry.  
The output you see is what I got from the Kafka consumer console reading from the topic. The desired output format is JSON but since I send the JSON message from a python script into rabbitMQ , then I use the connector to import the messages to the Kafka topic  and finally I write the results into ADLS Gen2 container using another Kafka connect connector...  when I have a look to final JSON file in ADLS I got those characters encoded in Base64.. Not sure whether I explained well..

Comment: JSON is just a string, so each connector should just use StringConverter on each piece

Comment: I agree with that, the thing is that  the rabbitMQ messages are converted into binary as @Soumen Mukherjee commented before. So it think this is the flow that the message I following, correct me if I´m wrong:

Original Message (JSON) --> RabbitMq (ByteArray) --> Kafka (ByteArray) -->ADLS (JSON)

Comment: So basically now i´m receiving the message in JSON format but the content is still encoded in Base64 making it unusable . Any idea?

   "format.class":"io.confluent.connect.azure.storage.format.json.JsonFormat",
   "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.azure.datalake.gen2.AzureDataLakeGen2SinkConnector",

Comment: I've not used the Azure storage. Maybe it requires the data the data in a particular format. For example, using ByteArrayConverter then JsonFormat will put bytes into a JSON string, which would explain why you see `[B@1583a488`. The data must be deserialized to a String with StringConverter before written to JSON